# How can I rotate a sign in spigot 1.19.3?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have a probleam about the signs in minecraft.

I don't know how to rotate (north, south, east, west, using the view of player) them in JAVA using the spigot library. I try to do that with blockData and Facing, but don't work so well, then how can I do it?

```
block.setType(Material.OAK_SIGN); // Check if it gives problems to the code!
if (block.getState() instanceof Sign) {
   Sign new_sign = (Sign) block.getState();
   new_sign.setLine(1, "My line");
   new_sign.update();
}
```

Version of MC: 1.19.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the direction of a sign, you should use the [`Rotatable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/data/Rotatable.html) state as you are using `Sign` :

```java
if(b.getState().getBlockData() instanceof Rotatable) {
    BlockData bd = b.getState().getBlockData();
    ((Rotatable) bd).setRotation(BlockFace.EAST);
    b.setBlockData(bd);
    b.getState().update();
}
// now it's direction east
```

[BlockFace enum](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/BlockFace.html)

Also, if you have a [`WallSign`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/data/type/WallSign.html), you will have access to this, so be sure it's a Sign and not a WallSign.

Comment: Do you have logs ? Can you print something to be sure it's a directional sign ?

Comment: `block.setType(Material.OAK_SIGN);
                 if (block.getState() instanceof Sign) {
                 Sign new_sign = (Sign) block.getState();
  if (block.getState() instanceof Directional) {
                             player.sendMessage("Directional Block!");
    }` . Don't print anything... Then all sign aren't Directional? How it possible? @Elikill58

Comment: I don't know, as my answer said, `Sign` is not directional, but `WallSign` is. Through it would be the opposite. Does the sign well change the line ? If not, can you check with the `if (block.getState() instanceof Directional)` outside of the `Sign` check ?

Comment: I've tried doing the same thing from outside the IF of instanceof Sign as well and it prints absolutely nothing. @Elikill58

Comment: I try now with wall_sign and is the same thing.

Comment: And did you tried to place an oak wall sign instead of oak sign ?

Comment: Nope, don't work @Elikill58

Comment: Don't work but i accept your answear

Comment: Thanks for this, but as it wasn't working, it's not recommended. I just updated the answer as I have a working way ! :)

Comment: Uh, thanks :) , Now i try do work on it @Elikill58

Comment: It's WORKK!!!! ly